# Cannot deploy MEAN stack application on Oracle

Tags: cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have developed a MEAN stack application which I want to deploy on Oracle cloud. I tried zipping  manifest.js file and my app.js file and uploading it on oracle cloud. But it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Removed the Oracle tag as this is not related to Oracle database.

Comment: Which Oracle Cloud Service did you try to upload this to? Application container? Compute?